# Is the set =(-1,1)∩ℚ Open in ℚ with the usual metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the set =(−1,1)∩ℚ just clopen in ℚ with the usual metric

I’m assuming it’s just open because although the limit points aren’t in our set, it is in our metric space. I can’t think of why it would be closed. Would it be?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: My apologies, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is indeed open. Let $x \in (-1, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}.$

Let $\epsilon = \min\{x+1, 1-x\}.$ Both these quantities are positive by choice of $x$ and hence, $\epsilon > 0$.

Now, simply consider the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ and see that this is contained in $(-1, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}.$ Thus, $x$ is an interior point of $B$. As $x$ was arbitrary, we are done.

---

In fact, something more general is true:
Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open (in $\mathbb{R}$). Then the set $B = A \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

The converse is true as well!
Given any open subset $B$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists an open subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $B = A \cap \mathbb{Q}$.